# How to convert YAML to WADL

Tags: rest, yaml, wadl

I have a YAML file I have created using swagger. I want to use use this in Jdeveloper to create a Service Bus component. However, JDeveloper takes only WADL file as input, I want to convert my YAML file into a WADL. Is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: YAML is a general data format. WADL is a specific XML schema. You're searching for a tool to convert an OpenAPI specification (which is what Swagger uses and which happens to be written in JSON or YAML) to WADL. Asking for such off-site resources is off-topic on SO but perhaps knowing the right terms will help you. Generally, it doesn't really make sense to create a specification in one format when you require to have it in a different format.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is totally valid. JDeveloper/SOA Suite only supports WADL format. Trying to import Swagger YAML will not work (at least in the current 12.2.1.4). You can perform the conversion from Swagger WADL or JSON using SOAP-UI. Create first SOAP UI project, import Swagger JSON or YAML. Once done you can click on the "WADL Content" -tab on the project window. Save this WADL to a file and import to your JDeveloper project.